# How to run multiple commands repeatedly on centos?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I have many tasks, which are something like `java -jar task1.jar` and `java -jar task2.jar` and so on. All the tasks take different time to complete.  I want to run them simultaneously and run again when completed. Is there a good way to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want to wait both commands to finish before restarting them?

Comment: No, I want each task to run again in 10 minutes  when it completed.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run both commands in background **and restart them** as soon as they will finish with a 10 minutes pause (your comments here below).

Something like this will restart each command independently:

```
$ while true ; do java -jar task1.jar ; sleep 600 ; done &
$ while true ; do java -jar task2.jar ; sleep 600 ; done &
```

If you want to wait **both** commands to finish before restarting them:

```
$ while true ; do
    java -jar task1.jar &
    java -jar task2.jar &
    wait
    sleep 600
  done
```

As per you comment I did add a 10 minutes pause before re-running the commands...

Comment: In the first condition, how can I add a sleep?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can run all those instructions in background mode

#### syntax

```
long_command with arguments > redirection &
```

Here in your case, it would be

```
java -jar task1.jar &
java -jar task2.jar &
```

Both will run in background mode and they will run in parallel.

#### To run the program 'n' number of times

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0
n=10

while [ $a -lt $n ]
do
    java -jar task1.jar &
    java -jar task2.jar &
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

#### Infinite run with conditional break

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0

while true
do
   echo "Running "$a "th time"
   if [ $a -eq 5 ]
   then
      break
   else
      java -jar task1.jar &
      java -jar task2.jar &
   fi
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

You can put your desired condition in `if` block.